# Which is the best way to share data among akka actors?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor

I have a list of objects that are generated by each actor in my system and at the end of completion of all actors,the data generated are used for next process. When i searched about this topic,very few answers where found. Which of the below is the best approach :

1. actor Agent
2. A Map created with an actor,which has methods to update content on receiving messages.

Which would be the right way to share data. If none of the above options are right way,then Is there any other approaches available? And can the agent be shared among sub actors?

Answer (score 0):

I would  try to model this workflow that you describe, "in the end of completion of all actors the data generated is used for next step" with actors and messages before I would try out mixing in any other abstractions.

Without knowing more about your specific problem: You could have one managing actor send the needed data with the request messages, when every actor is done with their workload they send it back to the actor that sent the request, which then gathers it and puts it in the messages of the next request.